# Mutt: let vim handle syntax highlighting when viewing plain text attachment

Tags: email, vim, syntax-highlighting, mutt

I use `mutt` for e-mail and I let `vim` handle plain text attachments. In my `~/.mailcap` I have

`text/plain; view %s ; needsterminal`

That works fine, but it removes all syntax highlighting. I often receive source code in attachments, and it'd be great to have syntax highlighting. Is there an option that would allow me to preserve it?

I've also tried `vim -R -- %s ; needsterminal` in `~/.mailcap` but the result is the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your ~/.muttrc:

```
set allow_ansi
```

That, along with your mailcap rule, worked for me to see a `.diff` attachment with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that isn't working for me. Mutt now displays things like `gpg: Good signature, etc.` in color, as those are probably surrounded by ANSI color codes, but still not joy with syntax highlighting in attachments.

Comment: Unfortunately, superuser is not a good forum for troubleshooting. A number of possible issues come to mind, though. Does the `view` found by `mutt` have syntax highlighting? (`:version`) Does `view` think it's in a color terminal? (`:set term? t_Co?`) Did `view` detect the 'filetype'? (`:set ft?`) Did `view` choose a syntax file? (`:echo b:current_syntax?`) When `view` is displaying an attachment, can it be made to display color at all? (`:help colortest.vim`)

Comment: When run from the command line, `view` behaves perfectly and has syntax highlighting. There's only one `view` on my system. I suspect `mutt` somehow removes the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought I'd share my solution;
In my `mailcaprc` I've added `text/plain; vim -u <path to my vimrc> - ; needsterminal`(the dash is important)

This allows me open the plaintext in vim with my own config by using the `m` shortcut when opening the plain-text file as an attachment.